# Apply (map) function to CERTAIN Pandas dataframe elements

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas, dataframe, map-function

I'm trying to apply a time discounting function on only the datetime cells in the following dataframe. The first column has a user ID and scattered through the rest of the dataframe are pandas date time entries.

[image]

The time discounting function I would like to use relies on a time delta between elements within the dataframe and some other time. If `t` is time `t=g.ix[11:,6]` then `h` is a dataframe of a few time_deltas `h=t-g[g.ix[:,1:]!=0]` as shown below.

[image]

Is it possible to apply the function

```
def calc_time_discount(t_delta):
        t_delta=t_delta.days
        if t_delta <= 14:
                d=18.375/(t_delta-24.5)+1.75
        else:
                d=0
        return d
```

to `h` such that all the datetime entries (without changing the `np.nans` to dates themselves) would produce a discount factor (which happens to be a value between 1 and 0) that I can store in a new dataframe the same size as h (or g for that matter)?

Of the 20+ stack overflow questions I've looked through on the topic none address how one would go about applying a function to only certain elements of a dataframe.

**Uber easy code sharing**

Here's a [zip with function and g.pkl](https://www.dropbox.com/s/3o8bvxoiw06b0bu/StackOverflow.zip?dl=0) for loading (I promise it doesn't have any viruses in it).

Comment: Have you tried to apply your function only on notnull elements ?

```h.apply(lambda x: my_func(x) if(np.all(pd.notnull(x[1]))) else x, axis = 1)```

Comment: @FlorianGauthier Great inference.

Comment: @FlorianGauthier, if you make your comment the answer... I will accept it. Sorry for not replying earlier - your solution worked and I was out the gate developing my next 7 things

Comment: @zelusp there you go :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try applying your function only to not-null elements, like so :

```
h.apply(lambda x: my_func(x) if(np.all(pd.notnull(x[1]))) else x, axis = 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's the pandas function `notnull` applying checking for *not-null-ness* to one of my tables. The table `bookdates_charge1_df` consists of two columns: `BookDate` and `Charge1`.

I assign the table to itself but only after I have checked the elements of 'Charge1` are not null.

Recall 'Charge1' is a series (one-dimensional array, e.g. single column). Therefore [this function](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.notnull.html) must be applied.

```
bookdates_charge1_df = bookdates_charge1_df[
    bookdates_charge1_df.Charge1.notnull()
]
```

If you try to do

```
bookdates_charge1_df = bookdates_charge1_df[
    'Charge1'.notnull()
]
```

The interpreter will complain the string does not have the attribute 'notnull'. Because it doesn't. (I don't know what you tried, but I'm just adding this in case you tried this. Next time, **please add what you have tried**!)

Comment: @florian had already pretty much answered my question despite not putting it as an official answer. I appreciate you taking the time to answer though!